# How to access dot-seperated request parameters on JSP by using JSTL tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, http-request-parameters

Below is an URL with a dot-separated request parameter `pager.offset`.

```
http://localhost:8081/panelistsListing?panel=&pager.offset=10
```

In JSP Page I was using that to reflect values in form fields

```
request.getParameter("pager.offset"); / ${param.parameter_name}
```

How to access pager.offset that should be  `${param.pager.offset}`

But I would like to do the same in JSP (with JSTL/EL). I tried a lot different expressions, but none of them printed the expected value.

```
${pager.offset}
${param.pager.offset}
<c:out value="${param.pager.offset}"/>  
<c:out value="${requestScope.pager.offset}"/>
<c:out value="${requestScope['pager.offset']}"/>
<c:out value="${pager.offset}" scope="request"/>
```

How can I access this dot-separated request parameter in JSP EL?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
${param['pager.offset']}
```